# Angular append an element to the child of current element inside of a directive

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying to append an element to a child element inside of a directives element. So I have this code:

```
directives.group = function ($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: '../../Content/templates/RecruitingGroups/Group.html',
        link: function (scope, el) {
            scope.addRule = function () {
                var rule = $compile('<rule></rule>')(scope);
                $(el).find('#rule').append(rule);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Notice in the link I have a function(). The function has scope and element passed into it. I thought 'el' would be unique and would be like doing a jQuery `addRule($this)`. But it appears this is not the case because if several of these `<group>` divs are on the page the code  `$(el).find('.getGroups').append(rule)` will append to the last instance of that element on the page. Not to `$this` like I imagined it would work.

My problem is how do I append this `<rule>` element to `this` directive. Not another one an the page.

Some Example HTML

```
<div>
    <group>
        <div ng-click="addRule()">
            <div id="rule">
                <rule></rule>
                <rule></rule>
            </div>
        </div>
    </group>
    <group>
        <div ng-click="addRule()">
            <div id="rule">
                <rule></rule>
            </div>
        </div>
    </group>
</div>
```

So in other words When I click `addRule()` I want it to append the `<rule>` element to the child `id="rule"` where you currently clicked the `addRule()` button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to Patrick's insight about scope, you may be able to avoid using jQuery by letting your model drive the DOM.  Here is a simple demo: http://plnkr.co/BD7cKTfR4iWhM5pHPoD4

```
app.directive('group', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: true,
        templateUrl: 'group.html',
        link: function (scope, el) {
            scope.rules = [];

            scope.addRule = function () {
                scope.rules.push({id: scope.rules.length});
            }
        }
    }
});
app.directive('rule', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: true, 
    templateUrl: 'rule.html'
  }
});
```

group.html template:

```
<div>
    <input type="button" value="add a rule" ng-click="addRule()" />
    <div>
        <rule ng-repeat="rule in rules"></rule>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: But wont this make the rule generate automatically on page load? I want to add the whole rule element when the user clicks a button.

Comment: No, this only creates a rule element if there are rules in scope.rules.  you can initialize that array with rules or nothing.  Up to you.

Comment: @allencoded, try the plunker in my answer.  you can see that no rules are created until the button is clicked.

Comment: I did and it worked perfectly I even added onto it to do what exactly my need is http://embed.plnkr.co/QKCd1LWhVjA47loohAom/preview

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you are not creating a new scope. So everytime you add the group directive, you are essentially replacing the "old" addRule function.

Try adding scope: true to your directive definition. Example:

```
directives.group = function ($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: true,
        templateUrl: '../../Content/templates/RecruitingGroups/Group.html',
        link: function (scope, el) {
            scope.addRule = function () {
                var rule = $compile('<rule></rule>')(scope);
                $(el).find('#rule').append(rule);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This will prototypically inherit the parent scope and then you will be able to define function addRule for each. In this case, the element (el) should be what you expect.

It would also probably be good to replace id with class as dave suggests since an id is intended to be unique within a document.

Comment: also, `#rule` should be unique to the page.  Since you are repeating the element, an id is not the correct choice, you should be using a class.